# Django- Creating a dynamic path for file upload in models.py

Tags: django, django-models

I am having a model :

```
class Attendance(models.Model):
    course = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    year = models.IntegerField(_('year'), choices=year_choices, default=current_year)
    sec = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=setFilePath, validators=[validate_file_extension])
```

and my setFilePath method goes like this :

```
def setFilePath(instance, filename):
    return 'attendance-record/{course}/{year}/{sec}/{subject}/'.format(course=instance.course, year=instance.year, sec=instance.sec, subject=instance.subject)
```

but I am not sure of this working ! Can anyone correct me, I want my file destination to be specific like this only and those fields are given in  other column of tables

I have searched how to do this and found some ways which includes using 
1. two Save method
2. Postgres way
Though I am using postgres I want the dir path to be same as this.

Comment: So is your question as to whether or not this will work, or if this is the right approach?

Comment: Also, are you intentionally wanting to leave out the filename in the filepath? I don't think that will work

Comment: Right approach and it is no working btw! Thanks @Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the example in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to), you are using the right approach. The reason why it is not working is that you have not included the `filename` in the path. So the solution would be:

```py
def setFilePath(instance, filename):
    return 'attendance-record/{course}/{year}/{sec}/{subject}/{filename}'.format(course=instance.course, year=instance.year, sec=instance.sec, subject=instance.subject, filename=filename)
```

Note that the default file path length is 100 characters. If you need to increase this, you can pass a `max_length` argument to your model definition, like so:

```py
file = models.FileField(upload_to=setFilePath, validators=[validate_file_extension], max_length=256)
```